# Why not using std::move everything?

Tags: c++, c++11

i don't undertstand fully this answer. Why we not all using type with std::move?

Example;

```
std::map<int, int> try;

void foo(std::map<int, int>& try, int t1, int t2)
{
    try.emplace(std::move(t1), std::move(t2));
}

int main()
{
    int k = 1;
    int v = 5;

    try.emplace(k , v); // emplace copies
    foo(try, k, v); // emplace referance
    return 0;
}
```

so what is the different emplace copies and emplace referance? I know std::move more efficient than use copies. (if i know wrong, sorry. I'm beginner) So what can i use? Using copies or std::move? Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Note that you can't use `try` as a variable name - it's a reserved word.

Comment: An `int` has no managed resources to move, so moving an `int` is exactly the same as copying an `int`.

Comment: @Eljay thanks for you answer!

Comment: Because even with `int` the value might change - live - https://godbolt.org/z/xrW419cPr  and then you don't have it's value anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for not always moving an object is that after moving an object, you don't have it anymore.

```
void f()
{
    Object o;
    o.stuff();
    SomeFunctionTakingAReference(o);
    o.stuff(); // your o object is still usable
    SomeFunctionTakingAReference(std::move(o));
    // Here your o object is not valid anymore. It's gone and you have a valid but different object
```

Comment: I would not say "is not valid anymore", that is too ambiguous. The object exists and is usable, but its **value** has gone (moved to another object of the same kind).